# How to copy a partition in SQL Server efficiently

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

During an ETL process I have to update a partitioned table in SQL Server 2012. The table has about 250 million rows in 150 partitions.

My idea was to copy the relevant partition (identified by period), do the updates on the copy and deploy the updated data by switching the partition back to the original table.

I´ve tried to copy the partition by

```
INSERT INTO myCopyTable
SELECT * FROM myProductionTable WHERE period = 201707
```

Unfortunately this is way too slow. (The execution plan is telling me, that most of the costs is because of table and index inserts.)

**Is there a more efficient way to copy an entire partition?**

I do not expect that it is necessary to rebuild indices when copying a whole partition.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE myProductionTable SWITCH PARTITION 201707 TO myCopyTable`?

Comment: @Siyual: that's not a copy, is it? Might as well update the partition directly then. (In fact, that's a good question: why *not* update the partition directly? Downtime?)

Comment: @JeroenMostert No, it's not - but I think I'm misreading the question

Comment: Why do you think an `UPDATE` on a copy is a better idea than updating directly? The whole point of a partitioned table is that the partitions behave almost as if they were separate tables, so an `UPDATE` that affects only one partition has little to no effect on the others in terms of locking.

Comment: @Siyual with this statement the data is not present in the productionTable during the also time consuming update ...

Comment: drop or disable all indexes on `myCopyTable` and, if necessary, recreate/rebuild after copy is done

Comment: "I do not expect that it is necessary to rebuild indices when copying a whole partition." This is true only if the indexes are already there in the first place. In other words, you gain absolutely nothing by updating another table, unless your update can profit from radically different indexes -- and even then you need to add the considerable time needed to copy the data first. The only way this scheme would make any kind of sense is if you absolutely cannot tolerate failed reads during the update, and you cannot use `SNAPSHOT` isolation.

Comment: To answer your question *directly*: the bottleneck is creating and filling the new table; that the source table is partitioned isn't relevant. A dedicated bulk (parallel) insert would speed things up a lot, but that can only be done from a client (like SSIS).